# How can I automatically find out which jQuery selectors are slow on my site ? Is there a plugin for this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, monitoring, performance-testing

I would like to automatically detect whenever a jQuery selector is slow (> some_millis) I want it to console log something about the line number.

My first idea would be to override the core jQuery selector code to insert such a test there, but are there existing plugins to achieve this, has anyone attempted something similar ? Could some browser tool do it (maybe filter the method calls in a profiler) ?

Note that I do not want to put some perf monitoring js code around each selector call !

Comment: What have you tried? Did you took a look into this? http://seesparkbox.com/foundry/jquery_selector_performance_testing maybe is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Slow is a relative term so you need to determine your threshold at which point you consider the selector slow first. Is a selector considered slow after a given execution time or is slow considered slow relative to other selectors?...

Comment: @War10ck I will decide about some max threshold, of course there could be many complex definitions of slow.

Comment: @RobertW.Hunter I am curious to see what already exists, a cheap call to `$ = time.func($);` like in the article (I was reading it) may do it. Maybe I just lack the keywords to find the best tool if there are some for this.

Comment: What I am looking for does not seem to be a widespread practice. I found mostly some people looking at some specific selectors. What I want to do would be monitor all selectors, test many pages and see if any selector is suspect. Of course all programmers should know about jQuery selectors and do efforts but you never know what you can find... Maybe some innocent looking selector is worse than you expected, maybe some external lib has a terrible selector in it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick google search yields:

1. http://seesparkbox.com/foundry/jquery_selector_performance_testing
2. https://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/

The reference to the JS profiler is dead, but here is a preferable way via Chrome:

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/cpu-profiling

> Now open the Chrome DevTools, navigate to the Profiles panel, and verify "Collect JavaScript CPU Profile" is selected. Now, click the Start button or press Cmd + E start recording a JavaScript CPU profile.

Comment: Looks like browser profiling would only work on a per tab basis. Those Chrome Profiling tools look a bit better than the Firefox ones. Should investigate those.

Comment: Note that time.js is not available: https://remysharp.com/time.js, but can still do something along the lines of the article. I can google too you know, I was wondering if someone had done/tried this and had some experience. It turns out no one does it. The problem is unless you have tons of data you may not notice those performance issues in advance unless you do what I describe in the question.